# max number of digit int scanner can take

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read in the user input of credit card number. However I got an input mistmatch after entering 10 digits. Anything below 10 digits works fine for my code.

```
 do{

    System.out.print("Please enter your creditcard number:");
    ccNum = scan4.nextInt();
    int length = String.valueOf(ccNum).length();
    if(length !=12)
    {
       ccNumInfo=false;
        System.out.println("Please enter a 12 digit card number");
    }
  }while(ccNumInfo!= true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a problem of the scanner, it's a limitation on Java's `int`. Being a 32-bit number, it does not accept values beyond it's maximum value of `2147483647`.

If you need to have 12 digits, use `long` instead. It is a 64-bit number with the upper limit of `9223372036854775807`.

Using a string and validating it to contain only digits may be another acceptable solution for reading and storing card numbers: it works even for 12-digit card numbers that have leading zeros (neither `long` nor `int` would preserve leading zeros in your numbers).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry i didnt had any chance to work with long number of values to realise that.